# Show that $A:=\left \{ \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \} $ is open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given with $|\cdot |_\infty$. Is $A:=\left \{
> \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \} $ open or
>   closed?

I suppose it is not open. I visualized the set the following:

[image]

I know that there can be no $\varepsilon$-Ball such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset A$ for all $x\in A$. I don't really know how to justify/prove it though...

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, the balls in the $\lvert \bullet\rvert_\infty$ stay with vertical and horizontal sides, even if the tangent to some curve passing through them is directed otherwise.

Comment: thanks, will fix it :)

Comment: It is neither open nor closed.

Comment: But $\partial A$ is not empty...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not  open since you then cannot be an open square inside the curve.

Indeed take the point $p=(1,1)\in A$ and assume that there exists an open square  $B$ centered at $p$ with  diameter $r$.
Take the point $q=(1+\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that  $q \in B$.

Note that  $q$ has not equal to a point   $(t_0,\frac{1}{t_0})$ for some $t_0 \in (\frac{1}{4},4)$ because then we would have that $(1+\epsilon)=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ thus $\epsilon=-2<0$ which is a contradiction.

Also it is not closed.

Take the sequence $x_n=(t_n,\frac{1}{t_n})$ for $t_n=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{n}$ which converges to $ (\frac{1}{4},4) \notin A$

with respect to $|\cdot|_2$.

But $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}^2$ we have that $|x|_{\infty} \leq|x|_2$

Comment: "It is not open since you then cannot be an open square inside the curve."  That's what I am thinking aswell, but how can one formalize it?

Comment: Formally, show that every nonempty open set contains points that do not satisfy $y=1/x$.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But I'm having trouble with doing that in respect to $|\cdot |_\infty$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic i edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not open because $(1,1)\in A$ but, for any $r>0$, the open ball $B_r\bigl((1,1)\bigr)$ is not a subset of $A$ (for instance, $\left(1,1+\frac r2\right)\in B_r\bigl((1,1)\bigr)\setminus A$).

And it is not closed because, since it is bounded, if it was closed it would be compact. But it is clear that $A$ is homeomorphic to $\left(\frac14,4\right)$ (just consider the map from $A$ onto $\left(\frac14,4\right)$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x$), which is not compact.

Comment: "it is clear that $A$ is homeomorphic to $(1/4,4)$" ... this seems to be **way beyond** OP's knowledge.

Comment: No need to downvote. I am always open to new strategies.